# Starting new activity with intent throws serializable exception

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization

Basically I am saving my object as a Serializable in a Bundle, and then save the Bundle in the Intent via `putExtras()`. If I get the Serializable from the Bundle on the same Activity, I am able to do so successfully:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("value", myObj);

    i.putExtras(bundle);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MyObj temp = (MyObj) bundle.getSerializable("value");
        }
    }, 3000);
```

However, when I call `startActivity()` to move to the second Activity, the app crashes on that line:

```
02-28 10:07:29.576 14929-14929/com.mopub.simpleadsdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.mopub.simpleadsdemo, PID: 14929
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1527)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
                                                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
                                                                         at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
                                                                         at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8687)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3082)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4228)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4186)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4525)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4493)
                                                                         at com.mopub.simpleadsdemo.BannerActivity$2.run(BannerActivity.java:81)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                      Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController$1
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1522)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475) 
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724) 
                                                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408) 
                                                                         at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157) 
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764) 
                                                                         at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8687) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3082) 
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518) 
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4228) 
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4186) 
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4525) 
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4493) 
                                                                         at com.mopub.simpleadsdemo.BannerActivity$2.run(BannerActivity.java:81) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Why is this happening? I want to retrieve the object in my second Activity. I have access to the source code of this third-party library (the `AdViewController` class), and have made it `implements Serializable`. Checking `instanceof Serializable` shows that `myObj` has been serialized.

Comment: Have you solved this problem.I'm having such problem where it's trying to serialize recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

The main cause of your problem is this:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController
```

which means that your class is not serializable. Make sure the AdViewController also implements the serializable interface

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that MyObj has implement Serializable interface before you want use
 bundle.putSerializable("value", myObj).

```
public class MyObj implements  Serializable{
     ......
}
```